# Applying a function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform some text analysis on a `pandas` `dataframe`, but am having some trouble with the flow.  Alternatively, maybe I just not getting it...  PS - I'm a python beginner-ish.

Dataframe example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Document' : ['a','1','a', '6','7','N'], 'Type' : ['7', 'E', 'Y', '6', 'C', '9']})


     Document   Type
0    a          7
1    1          E
2    a          Y
3    6          6
4    7          C
5    N          9
```

I'm trying to build a flow that if 'Document' or 'Type' is a number or not, do something.

Here is a simple function to return whether 'Document' is a number (edited to show how I am trying some if/then flow on the field):

```
def fn(dfname):
    if dfname['Document'].apply(str.isdigit):
        dfname['Check'] = 'Y'
    else:
        dfname['Check'] = 'N'
```

Now, I `apply` it to the dataframe:

```
df.apply(fn(df), axis=0)
```

I get this error back:

```
TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", u'occurred at index Document')
```

From the error message, it looks that I am not handling the index correctly.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Lastly - this may or may not be related to the issue, but I am really struggling with how `indexes` work in `pandas`.  I think I have run into more issues with the index than any other issue.

Comment: You should use bool rather than 'Y' and 'N'... !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close.

The thing you have to realize about apply is you need to write functions that operate on scalar values and return the result that you want. With that in mind:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Document' : ['a','1','a', '6','7','N'], 'Type' : ['7', 'E', 'Y', '6', 'C', '9']})

def fn(val):
    if str(val).isdigit():
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'

df['check'] = df['Document'].apply(fn)
```

gives me:

```
  Document Type check
0        a    7     N
1        1    E     Y
2        a    Y     N
3        6    6     Y
4        7    C     Y
5        N    9     N
```

#### Edit:

Just want to clarify that when using `apply` on a series, you should write function that accept scalar values. When using `apply` on a DataFrame, however, the functions should accept either full columns (when `axis=0` -- the default) or full rows (when `axis=1`).

Comment: OK - I think I just figured it out - to use functions on a dataframe, you have to use (should use) apply. So, I can chain together functions by using apply inside of the main function.  Is that right (does that make sense)?

Comment: @mikebmassey that sounds possible in theory, but it also sounds like a mess. i would avoid that situation.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that you can do this (without using apply, so more efficiently) using [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html):

```
In [11]: df['Document'].str.contains('^\d+$')
Out[11]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Document, dtype: bool
```

*Here the regex ^ and $ mean start and end respectively.*