# How to convert unaware datetime strings into aware datetime objects with timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, timezone

I am running queries into Big Query and Postgres Databases and return the results as lists, which I later on transform into pandas dataframes. The results look something like this:

```
| date                | column2 | column3 |
|---------------------|---------|---------|
| 2019-05-01 17:05:00 | ....... | ....... |
| 2019-05-01 17:10:00 | ....... | ....... |
| 2019-05-01 17:10:00 | ....... | ....... |
| 2019-05-01 17:15:00 | ....... | ....... |
| ................... | ....... | ....... |
```

The issue is that the date was a of date - timestamp type when on the database and this type is lost during the download. So now it is a string.

Another issue is that since the SQL queries I run take timezones into consideration the datetime strings that are saved into the dataframe are aware, although there is nothing to show (like a utc offset).

Now, since I know what their timezone should have been I am trying to convert those aware datetime strings into aware datetime objects.

But I have run into multiple problems, like:

- can't convert pandas timestamp object into python datetime object for the whole "date" column,
- when I force a BST timezone "2019-05-01 17:00:00" and use `to_pydatetime()` I get something like "2019-05-01 17:00:00 +01:00" and I don't know what it means and
- I want to get the string or datetime from the "2019-05-01 17:00:00 +01:00" with the offset included in the time.

**To sum up**, let's say I download results where every datetime aware string should be of BST timezone and the first date is `2019-05-01 17:05:00`.

How can I let python know that the above time is in BST meaning:

- when I compare it with `2019-05-01 17:05:00 UTC` it should be lower than that since `2019-05-01 17:05:00 BST` is actually `2019-05-01 16:05:00  UTC`

How can I convert it from the string type that it is into a python datetime object of the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" where the offset is included, meaning:

- when I print the "%H" part it should be 17. At the same time if I print the offset it should be +00:00 because it has already being "applied".

Please let me know if something doesn't make sense or if I have misunderstood something crucial about timezones in python and general in machines.

Any answer that helps me understand more is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add awareness I think [`dt.localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

aware = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/London')
>>> aware
0   2019-05-01 17:05:00+01:00
1   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
2   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
3   2019-05-01 17:15:00+01:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
```

Note that `+01:00` here is a notation for timezone info, indicating that one hour has been added to UTC/GMT time to obtain this timestamp (at least I see it that way).
Now if you want to convert to `utc` use [`dt.tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
utc = aware.dt.tz_convert('utc')
>>> utc
0   2019-05-01 16:05:00+00:00
1   2019-05-01 16:10:00+00:00
2   2019-05-01 16:10:00+00:00
3   2019-05-01 16:15:00+00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

**Update: deal with `NonExistentTimeError`**

From the docs I've linked above, [`dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):
when you have a time that *does not exist in a particular timezone where clocks moved forward due to DST*, consider `nonexistent` or `errors` parameters (better `nonexistent`).

`nonexistent` allow you to choose among:

- shift forward
- shift backward
- set a custom shift
- set to `NaT`
- raise `NonExistentTimeError` (default)

**Example:** (added `2019-03-31 01:00:00` according to your comment)

```
aware = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent="shift_forward")
>>> print(aware)
0   2019-05-01 17:05:00+01:00
1   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
2   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
3   2019-05-01 17:15:00+01:00
4   2019-03-31 03:00:00+01:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/London]


aware = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent="NaT")
>>> print(aware)
0   2019-05-01 17:05:00+01:00
1   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
2   2019-05-01 17:10:00+01:00
3   2019-05-01 17:15:00+01:00
4                         NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
```

Comment: Hey, although it doesn't quite solve all it's the closest I have gotten to. There is an issue though. If I have a string from `2019-03-31 01:00:00` until `2019-03-31 01:59:59` it will throw an error like : `pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2019-03-31 01:15:00`, because the time doesn't exist in real life. How can I tackle this since in your answer above you do this to the whole column and not to each element?

Comment: Updated. PS: If you want to customize a function, for example on the base of particular row values, consider also `apply` or `transform` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269599/applying-a-function-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just added `ambiguous = len(df['date']) * [True]` for a similar error to nonexistent to make it work. And my other issue is that `shift_forward` does push the time but even if it's 01:15 it pushes it to 03:00 like in your example. Instead of pushing it to 02:15. But I ll try to figure it out.

Comment: hey, glad it helped. I think `shift_forward` pushes to the first valid time, no matter the time you are pushing. According to the docs, pass a `timedelta` object for a custom shift, like `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent=pd.Timedelta(hours=1))`