# Replace rows in one dataframe with rows from a different dataframe through a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace rows in a dataframe with rows from another dataframe. I have an excel file with all the existing product code in column 0 called 'MASTER.xlsx', and where the remaining columns are empty. I have another excel file called 'COUT PROJET - HOTEL DE VILLE.xlsx' containing some of the product codes in column 0 and where the remaining columns are filled with values.

Ultimately, I want to iterate through both the 'MASTER.xlsx' and 'COUT PROJET - HOTEL DE VILLE.xlsx' files. When the product code is in both files, I want to replace that respective row in 'MASTER.xlsx' with the filled out row from 'COUT PROJET - HOTEL DE VILLE.xlsx'. When the product code is not in 'COUT PROJET - HOTEL DE VILLE.xlsx', I want that row in 'MASTER.xlsx' to remain unchanged (empty).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import glob

df_master = pd.read_excel('MASTER.XLSX')

df = pd.read_excel('COÛT PROJET - HÔTEL DE VILLE.xlsx')

for index, column in df.iterrows(): 
        for index, row in df_master.iterrows():
            if row['DATE :'] == column['DATE :']:
                df_master.update(df)
            else:
                continue
                
        
df_master.to_excel('UPDATED COÛT PROJET - HÔTEL DE VILLE.xlsx')
```

The current code seems to partly work, however I think because the dataframes don't have the same size. I have included pictures of what the excel files look like. I apologize for my lack a knowledge, I am a beginner trying to help out the family business.
Thank you for the help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25oHX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6QJ4.jpg)

Comment: Please include, sample input & expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do most things in pandas without loops.

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0'],
                     'B': ['B0'],
                     'C': ['C0'],
                     'D': ['D0']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0','','','',''],
                    'B': ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5'],
                    'C': ['C0','','','',''],
                    'D': ['D1','D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5']})

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, sort=False).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to avoid using crude loops when using pandas. These are much slower and inefficient. The best method is to use the `apply` feature in pandas, documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Here are a few examples on how to use apply, [example 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-apply/), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481039/python-pandas-apply-function), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269599/applying-a-function-to-pandas-dataframe).